# How does a Ghost go to the Underworld, and Back, to get to Rank 3+?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

As I recall in the GMC rules update, 
it is stated that Ghosts can not get beyond rank 2, without going to the underworld.
Ghost are also not interesting in most games while they are in the underworld (its pretty hard to get to).
So I want my rank 3 ghost to be back in the "real" world.

How do ghosts get out of the underworld?
Is it basically restricted to some other supernatural (such as a SinEater, Mage, Demon, Death-spirit/angel...), or mortal (using a ritual) opening a avernian gateway and the ghost sneaking out?

For a ghost to go to the underworld, it needs to have all its anchors destroyed.
But if all its anchors are destroyed, how can it stay back, if it finds its way back?

A friend tells me that the way for a ghost to create new anchors is to use the Create (or Mass-Create) Influence ability, using its Influence Anchors.

But create is not available til Rank 4 (influences can't exceed ranks).

How does this work out?

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways that this can happen. I'll break it apart into two sections: how to get out & how to stay out. You' ll have to pick an approach and go for it.

First, how to get back:

1. The ghost finds his way back up and:

   - Breaks out: by using the **Avernian Gateway** manifestation (God-Machine Chronicle p224).
   - Waits near an **Avernian Gateway** until it's opened (hopefully you've reached it and found the Key).
   - You open a **Graveyard Gate** near the Ghost's location (Book of the Dead p51-53)
2. Research a **summoning ritual** (God-Machine Chronicle p230-231)

Second, stay out:

1. Provide the Ghost with a willing host on which it can use the **Fetter** manifestation
2. Provide the Ghost with a willing host to **Posses** (and eventually **Claim**)
3. **Bind** the Ghost to a location (God-Machine Chronicle p232) or person (basically a Sin-Eater without any of the advantages and a whole slew of new disadvantages)
4. Assuming the Ghost has reached Rank 4, use the **Create** Influence to have a "temporary" anchor which is permanent (God-Machine Chronicle p222-223) for 6 Essence.

If you get him out and there's no method to make him stay out, the ghost will suffer Essence bleed and drop into hibernation.

---

Other, more exotic ways:

- The Ghost experiences a personal relevation (gains the **Lucid Dead** Numen; see Mummy - The Curse p209). Now he can recreate an Anchor. This also opens more doors (like **Intruder** or **Revenant**)
- Ask a Sin-Eater to go and get the ghost (assuming he / she has **Stygian Caul** at 5; Book of the Dead p78)

I'm sure I have missed some, but that's what I found on a diagonal scan of the material that I have.

Comment: No summoning rituals researchable in GMC can summon a ghost back from the Underworld. They only create/progress Conditions that allow an entity to appear, but a ghost in the Underworld has no Anchors on earth to even start with. Binding them within a location/circle won't stop Essence Bleed, and you can't bind an entity to a person, only within a boundary.